# How to multiply many matrices in one go in python?

Tags: python, numpy, matrix-multiplication

Suppose I have four matrices, `a`, `b`, `c`, and `d`.

In Python (with numpy), I need to do `result = np.matmul(np.matmul(np.matmul(a,b),c),d)` to multiply them.

In MATLAB/GNU Octave, I can multiply them in a much simpler manner, `result = a*b*c*d`.

Is there any way to multiply matrices in Python, so that I would not have to repeatedly write `np.matmul` avoid nested brackets?

Comment: More generally you can use [`functools.reduce`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.reduce)

Comment: I was using lists to implement matrices, they can be converted to numpy.matrix form with `aNew = np.asmatrix(a)`, and can be multiplied with `aNew@bNew@cNew@dNew`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the `@` operator. `result = a@b@c@d`.

Comment: I did `>>> a = [[1,2],[3,4]]`, followed by
`>>> a@a`, and got
`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for @: 'list' and 'list'
`

Comment: @ArchismanPanigrahi Why are you trying this with lists? You tagged `numpy`. Use `numpy.array` or `numpy.matrix`.

Comment: @ArchismanPanigrahi you'll want to change them into arrays where you define them with [`np.array()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.array.html)

Comment: I had implemented the matrices in a list, and used numpy to multiply them. Did not know about numpy arrays. Thanks.